# Mostrar datos de base de datos remota con Volley, Android

Tags: android, android-studio, webservice, android-volley, volley

Actualmente estoy cargando todos los datos de la tabla en un ReciclerView y todo va OK. Ahora quiero hacer una búsqueda por nombre he modificado el .php quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
    // post para recoger el nombre
$nombre=$_POST['nombrecito'];

// intentar conectar al servidor con el usuario y contraseña anteriores
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname,$username,$password, $database);

/*
 * This is the "official" OO way to do it,
 * BUT $connect_error was broken until PHP 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.
 */
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}   


// realizar una consulta que selecciona todas los datos de la tabla_Animadores
$query_search = "select * from tabla_Animadores WHERE name='".$nombre."'";

// crear un array para almacenar el json
$json = array();

// lanzar la consulta
$query_exec = $mysqli->query($query_search);
if (!$query_exec) {
    echo "Falló la consulta de la tabla tabla_Animadores: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
else {      
    while($row = $query_exec->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        // almacena cada fila de la consulta en el array $json
        $json[]=$row;
    }       

}       

// cerrar la conexión con la BD mysql
$mysqli->close();   

// mostrar por pantalla y codificar el vector $json como JSON
echo json_encode($json);
```

?>

El código en Android Studio es el siguiente:

```
public class MuestraDatos extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

//Iniciación de variables
private final String JSON_URL = MiURL;
private JsonArrayRequest request;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private List<Animadores> listaPersonas;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_muestra_datos);


    listaPersonas = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewid);
    //obtenemos datos remotos
    jsonrequest();


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    //Botón flotante
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        finish();

        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;

}

//obtenemos datos remotos
private void jsonrequest() {

    request = new JsonArrayRequest(JSON_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = null;

                  for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                try {

                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    Animadores animadores = new Animadores();
                    animadores.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    animadores.setDescription(jsonObject.getString("description"));
                    animadores.setRating(jsonObject.getString("Rating"));
                    animadores.setCategorie(jsonObject.getString("categorie"));
                    animadores.setNb_episode(jsonObject.getInt("episode"));
                    animadores.setStudio(jsonObject.getString("studio"));
                    animadores.setImage_url(jsonObject.getString("img"));

                    //Añadimos el animadores a listaPersonas
                    listaPersonas.add(animadores);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //Muestra en el ReciclerView la listaPersonas (listaPersonas = todos los objetos extraidos del json)
            muestraEnReciclerView(listaPersonas);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    })     {

        public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("nombrecito", "Javi");

            return params;
        }
    };

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MuestraDatos.this);
    requestQueue.add(request);
}



private void muestraEnReciclerView(List<Animadores> listaAnimadores) {

    //Creamos un objeto de la clase RecyclerViewAdapter y le decimos carge la listaPersonas.
    RecyclerViewAdapter myadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, listaAnimadores);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter);

}
```

}

El problema es que no me carga ningún dato. Le estoy pasando como nombre a buscar *Javi* estando en la base de datos, pero no me carga nada. Sin embargo al no pasarle parámetros al .php por POST, SI que carga todos los registro de la base de datos.

Comment: Has revisado el LogCat que error o mensaje muestra? te sugiero imprimas en caso de error un mensaje dentro de : @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }

Comment: El caso es que no me da ningún error. Aparece la actividad del ReciclerView  sin ningún dato. Aparentemente vacía. Es por eso que no encuentro el porqué.

Comment: Si el problema esta en la petición imprime dentro de onErrorResponse() el mensaje, no lo estas imprimiendo y no tendrás idea del problema, agrega Log.e("ERROR,"onErrorResponse() " + error.getMessage());

Comment: Estoy depurando, y le he puesto un pointBreak al ErrorListener y NO entra en el listener error. He modificado a modo de prueba el .php y he puesto en la consulta el nombre de la persona en lugar del parámetro POST y todo OK, probándolo desde el navegador solo obtengo el registro que empieza por ese nombre, (ya sé que usando POST los parámetros no van en el navegador, sino ocultos al usuario; pero quería descartar que el .php estuviera bien construido). Pero cuando trato de mandar ese parámetro desde Android obtengo como resultado del json esto: [] (solo la apertura y cierre de los corchetes).

Comment: He corregido la construcción del request que arriba me falto poner parámetros. Queda así: request = new JsonArrayRequest (Request.Method.POST,JSON_URL,null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(). El caso es, que no sé si le estoy mandando el parámetro de manera correcta.

Comment: donde tienes el myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); ?

Comment: Hola, no estoy utilizando ese método. No se si me equivoco, pero notifyDataSetChanged() se utiliza cada que se quiera actualizar la lista. En este caso, como cuando no se utilizan parámetros (que sí funciona), la lista se crea nueva. Creo que el problema está, en que no le está llegando el parámetro por POST de manera adecuada, corregirme si me equivoco, ya que si pongo directamente el valor del parámetro en la consulta del fichero .php si que funciona.

Comment: Me gustaría que alguien me proporcionara un ejemplo limpio si puede ser o comentado, de cómo mandar un parámetro por post y luego poder recuperar los datos del objeto de la BBDD para después mostrarlos en un ReciclerView.